# JBoss EAP 6.3 EJB timer persistence

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

We are migrating from JBoss EAP5 to EAP 6.3. There is a file in EAP "ejb2-timer-service.xml" where one can choose to persist timer in local DB or not. What would be the equivalent in EAP 6? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From JBoss 7 is no longer supported persist EJB timers in database.
Timers are only persisted in the file system `standalone/data/timer-service-data`

[Ability to use alternate persistent stores for EJB timers](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-318)